# Use instance of child class instead of parent class given a condition

Tags: php, oop, design-patterns

I'm working on breaking up a large, monolithic class into several subclasses, but it's too much to do all at once so I'm looking to split them out one by one over several releases as time permits. It's an authentication class that authorizes some channel, so currently it looks like this:

```
$auth = new Auth($user, $data);
$output = $auth->authChannel($channelName);
```

Inside `Auth`, it basically looks like this:

```
public function __construct($user, $data)
{
    $this->user = $user;
    $this->data = $data;
}

public function authChannel($channel)
{
    $this->setUserData();

    if (isset(self::CHANNEL_AUTH_FUNCTIONS[$channel])) {
        $authFunction = self::CHANNEL_AUTH_FUNCTIONS[$channel];
        return $this->$authFunction();
    } else {
        // invalid channel
    }
}
```

So `self::CHANNEL_AUTH_FUNCTIONS` is basically `['channelA' => 'authChannelA', 'channelB' => 'authChannelB']`, etc., and all those functions are in this one class.

Now what I want to do, one at a time, is `if $legacyChannel => callLegacyFunction() / else $newChannel => instantiate its own class and call auth()`.

So I put `Auth.php` into its own namespace and have the new `Channel.php` class in that same namespace. And `Channel extends Auth`.

Currently I have this:

```
public function authChannel($channel)
{
    $this->setUserData();

    if (isset(self::CHANNEL_AUTH_LEGACY_FUNCTIONS[$channel])) {
        $authFunction = self::CHANNEL_AUTH_LEGACY_FUNCTIONS[$channel];

        if ($authFunction) {
            return $this->$authFunction();
        } else {
            $authClassName = __NAMESPACE__ . '\\' . ucwords($channel);
            $authClass = new $authClassName($user, $data);
            return $authClass->auth();
        }
    } else {
        // invalid channel
    }
}
```

Is there a better way to do this? Currently it seems a bit wasteful since two different objects are created and the `setUserData()` function for example would need to be called again I believe. I'm also wondering if there's a better way to get the dynamic class name other than through `__NAMESPACE__ . / . $className`.

Answer (score 1):

You'll have to work quite a bit until that code starts looking better. I'll try to suggest as few changes as possible, to make "migration" as painless as possible, although you are a few steps removed from a clean design.

To start with, you can create an `AuthStrategyInterface` for your new authentication classes.

```
interface AuthStrategyInterface
{
    public function supports(string $channel): bool;
    public function auth($user, $data);
}
```

Each of your new authentication classes should implement this interface. The method `supports($channel)` is easy enough to understand: if a authentication class can deal with certain channel, it should return true.

Your `Auth` class would need a way to get these strategies injected. Usually you would do that in the constructor... but to leave your API unchanged we'll just create a setter method for that.

When executing `authChannel()`, it will first check on the injected strategies to see if any supports the used `$channel`, and use that if possible. If not, goes back to check your old implementations.

This way you do not need to touch any of the old code as you add new authentication strategies. As you add new implementations, you are gradually [strangling](https://martinfowler.com/bliki/StranglerFigApplication.html) the legacy system. At one point no of the old implementations are used, and you can move on to a new code refactoring phase.

```
class Auth {
    private iterable $strategies = [];

    public function __construct($user, $data)
    {
        $this->user = $user;
        $this->data = $data;
    }

    public function setAuthStrategies(iterable $strategies)
    {
        $this->strategies = $strategies;
    }


    public function authChannel($channel)
    {
        $this->setUserData();

        // check if any of the new strategies supports  
        foreach ($this->strategies as $strategy) {
            if ($strategy->supports($channel) {
                return $strategy->auth($this->user, $this->data);
            }
        }

        // check "legacy" authentication methods.
        if (isset(self::CHANNEL_AUTH_FUNCTIONS[$channel])) {
            $authFunction = self::CHANNEL_AUTH_FUNCTIONS[$channel];
            return $this->$authFunction($this->user, $this->data);
        }

        // no valid authentication method
        return false;     
    }
}
```

To use it, you would do something like this:

```
$fooAuthStrategy = new FooAuthStrategy();
$barAuthStrategy = new BarAuthStrategy();
$bazAuthStrategy = new BazAuthStrategy();

$auth = new Auth($user, $data);
$auth->setAuthStrategies(
    [
        $fooAuthStrategy,
        $barAuthStrategy,
        bazAuthStrategy
    ]
);

$auth->authChannel($channel);
```

The specifics would change according to how exactly your application is set-up, but something like this would take you further in a good direction than your current approach.

Comment: Hey @yivi, thanks for the response -- this is helpful! I have a couple of questions: 1. Basically, there's going to be an Auth class per channel, meaning that one class can support one channel. With that said, is there a need for iterating through `$strategies` and checking `supports($channel)` when I already have a one-to-one mapping of `$channels => Classes`? And out of curiosity, 2. how come we use `iterable` in the type hint here instead of just `array`?

Comment: Also, since I largely have control over all classes in the chain, definitely open to hearing about different design patterns that might better suit this problem (even if I only have time to, for example, implement "Step 1" of what might be a Several Step approach to a clean design)

Comment: 1.) Iterating and checking `supports()` simply frees you from having to maintain that map of auth->channels. You implement a new auth class, implement the appropriate `supports()` method, and you do not have to touch anything else. 2.) An `array` is a type of `iterable`.

Answer (score -1):

I don't know if I understood the question correctly, but you couldn't do it like that?

```php
 public function authChannel($channel)
{
    $this->setUserData();

    if (!isset(self::CHANNEL_AUTH_LEGACY_FUNCTIONS[$channel])) {
        // Invalid channel
        return;
    }
    return  self::CHANNEL_AUTH_LEGACY_FUNCTIONS[$channel]
            ? $this->$authFunction()
            : parent::auth();
}
```

Comment: Well this assumes it's being called from the child function, right? My situation is that they would be calling `Auth`, the parent function, but (potentially) passing in the name of the child class, so I need something more like return $legacy ? $this->$authFunction() : child::auth();

Comment: Sorry ShaneOH, I didn't understand you correctly.  You can dynamically instantiate the son within the father (as you did in the example)  but this is an unpatronizing and very ugly, consider create a class that acts as a auth provider and provide you the auth class instance to use.